# changing the background color of the page by array and loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i use this code it change the background color yo yellow in one time and i want to change the color one by one red then blue then green and so on.....thanks in advance

```js
var colorss = ["red", "blue", "green","maroon","yellow"];
    
    for (i=0;i<colorss.length;i+=1) {
        
        
            document.body.setAttribute('style',"background-color:" + colorss[i]);
            
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function changeColor(selector, colors, time) {
    var curCol = 0,
      timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (curCol === colors.length) curCol = 0;
        $(selector).css("background-color", colors[curCol]);
        curCol++;
      }, time);
  }
  $(window).load(function() {
    changeColor(".container", ["green", "yellow", "blue", "red"], 3000);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -khtml-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

OR

using CSS only:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  -webkit-animation: background 5s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) infinite;
  animation: background 5s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-color: #f99;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: #9f9;
  }
  67% {
    background-color: #99f;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #f99;
  }
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-color: #f99;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: #9f9;
  }
  67% {
    background-color: #99f;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #f99;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but the computer computes faster than you can see or the webpage can load.

also you have an **s** *too much in colors* `document.body.setAttribute('style',"background-color:" + colors[i]);`

here is working code if you want to see the loop

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green","maroon","yellow"];
let body = document.getElementById('body');

var i = 0;
function myLoop () {
   setTimeout(function () {
       document.body.setAttribute('style',"background-color:" + colors[i]);
      i++;
      if (i < colors.length) {
         myLoop();
      }
   }, 1500) /*1.5 seconds*/
}
myLoop();
```

```html
<body>
<h1>hello</h1>
</body>
```